# matplotlib.image.NonUniformImage extends beyond plot region during pdf export

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I am using matplotlib.image.NonUniformImage to generate a scientific plot. Unfortunately, the figure looks corrupted after pdf export. The color plot extends beyond the axes of the plot area. See example below. How can I avoid this problem?

```
from matplotlib.image import NonUniformImage
import numpy as np

testdata = np.random.rand(100,50)

# limits of the plot in x and y
extent = [0,100,0,50]

# create figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7.2,3.8))

# create color plot. 
im = NonUniformImage(ax, interpolation='bilinear', extent=extent)
im.set_data(range(100), range(50), testdata.T)
im.set_clim(0,1)

# add image to plot
ax.images.append(im)
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 50)

# add color bar
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('counts', rotation=90, va="bottom",labelpad=20)

# crop to visible area and save
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, bottom=.12, right=1, top=.93, wspace=0, hspace=0)
fig.savefig('./images/test.pdf')
```

Result (bottom-right corner):

[image]

The problem is not visible in my jupyter notebook and it does not occur when using imshow instead of NonUniformImage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  `ax.images.append(im)`
you just append the image to the list of images to draw. In order to have the image be clipped by the axes, you would still need to set its clip path

```
im.set_clip_path(ax.patch)
```